# 2 dimensional array lookup intersect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection

I want to write a code which will obtain the intersection value of a row and column of an array.
I've a table below which is a slab for calculating incentive of employees.

[image: Table: Achievement % & Sales Value]

When user puts achievements percent and sales value the result should be the intersection value of the respective column and row.
Example: When user puts 106-110 & 42000 in editText fields the result would come out 14919.

I did it in excel by **Vlookup** & **Match** function but I'm helpless here. I'm unable to figure out which formula would work here.

Comment: Can you show your code, how the data look like, do you have 2 dimension array in javascript or html?

Comment: this isn't a coding service and what is shown is not workable structured javscript data

Comment: Where do you get the data from? SQL Server? How are you processing it : Server side Scripts like PHP? Client side like JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need a search here at all. You may have it already built-in into the data (seems static enough).

If your array is defined like this:

```
var arr = {
    "60000": { 
        "100": "2,625",
        "101-105": "7,500"
            ....
    },
    "120000":{
        "100": "2,888",
        "101-105": "8,250"
            .....
    }
        ....
}
```

Then

```
arr["120000"]["100"]
"2,888"
```

But... why is it android?

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your data this way:

```
var array = [

  [ 2625, 2888 ... ], // index 0 ->100
  [ 7500, 8250 ...], // index 1 ->101-115

];
```

Enter the combination:

```
<select id="val1">
  <option value="0">100</option>
  <option value="1">101-105</option>
   ....
</select>

<select id="val2">
  <option value="0">60000</option>
  <option value="1">12000</option>
</select>
```

And than return the mapped value:

```
//... code to get val1 and val2

function getReward(row,col){

  return array[row][col];

}
```